# cual es la forma mas facil de colocar css a un archivo php?

Tags: php, css

Tengo un archivo php el cual se llama **login.php** en el cual tiene la vista del login y esta en php al hacer el enlace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\css\estilo_login.css" />
```

no me aparece el css en el navegador ,solo me aparece el titulo de login y los cuadros de correo y contraseña mi pregunta es si tiene que ver algo con que estoy trabajando con php o con xampp porque he visto probado con un archivo solo sin php y sin el xampp el cual funciono hice exactamente lo mismo en mi archivo login.php y no me aparece el css que hago?

codigo html

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gestion Turnos</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\css\estilo_login.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="../controlador/validar.php" method="post" name="frmlogin" id="frmlogin">  
      <input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario"/>
      <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave"/>
      <input type="submit" name="botoniniciar" id="botoniniciar" value="Iniciar sesi&oacute;n"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Código css:

```css
h1{
 color:green;
 font-family: verdana;
}
body{
 background:red;
}
```

estoy trabajando con block de notas y con xampp me encantaria que me ayudaran muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa que colocaste es la forma de hacerlo, sin embargo tu pregunta no es clara así que por favor lee [ask]

Comment: No te sirve más una ruta relativa que una estática?

Comment: te refieres a <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo_login.css" /> si es asi ya le he intentado

Comment: Coloca una imagen de tu directorio de trabajo, me gustaría ver cómo está el directorio vista

Comment: de las carpetas y todo los archivos?

Comment: De la carpeta vista que es donde estan los archivos en cuestión

Comment: ya  subi  la imagen

Comment: y despues que hago?

Comment: me dice que tengo que tener 20 de reputacion para poder hablar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que debes tener es por la ruta donde se encuentra tu css, veo que tu proyecto se encuentra en:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\

Además tienes un directorio para la vista:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\

En cuyo directorio tienes para organizar los archivos css:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\css\

Y supongo que tienes para organizar los archivos php o html:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\html\
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\php\

O simplemente los archivos html y php los tienes en tu directorio de vista.

Si tenemos que el archivo login.php se encuentra en:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\login.php

Entonces debes indicar que la ruta desde tu archivo hasta el css tiene que pasar primero por el directorio css, quedando:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\estilo_login.css" />
```

Ésto indica que desde donde se encuentre el archivo login.php se ingresará al directorio css y allí se seleccionará el archivo estilo_login.css.

Por otra parte si el archivo login.php se encontrara en:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\html\login.php 
>   o
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionturno\vista\php\login.html

Deberás indicar en el atributo href que desde donde se encuentra el archivo login.php se subirá (o se irá hacia atrás) un directorio, o sea desde el directorio html o php subirá a vista y una vez allí ingresará al directorio css y se seleccionará el archivo estilo_login.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\css\estilo_login.css" />
```

Los "..\" indican ese ir un directorio hacia arriba o hacia atrás.

Comment: hola zerecool no tengo separado el php y el html te explico, el archivo esta guardado en php pero adentro tiene html, por lo cual no tengo separa en archivos el php y el html, ya cambie lo que digiste y sigue sin aparecer el css ¿tendra algo que ver el xampp? de todas maneras muchas gracias

Comment: Si no lo tienes separado entonces lo tienes en vista, eso quiere decir que debes usar la primera opción. Ten cuidado de no colocar "\" al incio, ya que indicarías que estás yendo a la raíz del servidor. "css\estilo_login.css"

Comment: el codigo quedaria asi el cual aun no me muestra es css <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
     <head>
            <title>Gestion Turnos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\estilo_login.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
            <h1>Login</h1>
     <form action="../controlador/validar.php" method="post" name="frmlogin" id="frmlogin"> 
  <input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario"/>
  <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave"/>
  <input type="submit" name="botoniniciar" id="botoniniciar" value="Iniciar sesi&oacute;n"/>
     </form>
     </body>
</html>